# How to correctly save an object that has list of objects in database using ef

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I have this problem where I want to add a new `FormQuestion` to my form object and save it.
But when redirecting to another method my `Form` object doesn't have this new added `FormQuestion`.
When you press the add button it redirects you to:

```cs
public IActionResult CreateQuestion() 
        {
            int id = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("form-id"));

            Form form = db.Forms.Find(id);
            form.FormQuestions.Add(new FormQuestion());
            db.FormQuestions.Add(form.FormQuestions[^1]);
            db.Forms.Update(form);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var asd = db.Forms.Find(id); //a form with added question

            return RedirectToAction("CreateForm");
        }
```

But when redircting to "CreateForm":

```cs
public IActionResult CreateForm() 
        {
            Form form = new Form();

            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("form-id") != null)
            {
                int id = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("form-id"));
                form = db.Forms.Find(id); // a form without new added question
            }
            else 
            {
                db.Forms.Add(form);
                db.SaveChanges();
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("form-id", form.ID.ToString());
            }

            return View(form);
        }
```

My OnModelCreating() is:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Form>().HasMany(form => form.FormQuestions).WithOne();
        }
```

Form class:

```cs
public class Form
    {
        public List<FormQuestion> FormQuestions { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; private set; }
        public Form()
        {
            FormQuestions = new List<FormQuestion>();
        }
        public Form(string Heading)
        {
            this.Heading = Heading;

            FormQuestions = new List<FormQuestion>();
        }

        public void AddQuestion(string name, string answer) 
        {
            FormQuestions.Add(new FormQuestion()
            {
                Name = name,
                Answer = answer
            });

        }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

FormQuestion class:

```cs
public class FormQuestion
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

I dont know, maybe there are some problems with relationships.

`Update`
I finally got it working by just manually querying through all of the `FormQuestion`:

```cs
form.FormQuestions = db.FormQuestions.Where(i => i.Form == form).ToList();
```

I thought ef will do this automaticly.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow sontaksla. i do curious, did the newly added `FormQuestion` stored in the database?

Comment: @BagusTesa It is stored in the database, but when I get the `Form` object it is not in the list

Comment: is the `CreateQuestion` and `CreateForm` in the same controller? also, is this `db` provided using dependency injection or you have used other means?

Comment: @BagusTesa they are in the same controller and db is provided using dependency injection through the constructor. I even tested it with the debug mode and i dont get the problem i think there are some issues with the relationships